# Arranging in stack for 3 columns bothsided sidebars for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm designing a 3 column layout, for a responsive and mobile-friendly website, where the two columns will be in two sides of the content area. The following is a typical structure I always tend to follow.

```
<div id="inner-container">
    <aside id="left-sidebar">
       LEFT SIDEBAR
    </aside>
    <div id="content">
       CONTENT
    </div>
    <aside id="right-sidebar">
       RIGHT SIDEBAR
    </aside>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- #inner-container -->
```

But for responsive and mobile-friendly site, where the sidebar's less important than the content, and most of the cases we follow a stack order like this:

```
<div id="inner-container">
    <div id="content">
       CONTENT
    </div>
    <aside id="left-sidebar">
       LEFT SIDEBAR
    </aside>
    <aside id="right-sidebar">
       RIGHT SIDEBAR
    </aside>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- #inner-container -->
```

With this I can easily sort the two sidebar after the content in the lesser-width devices.

But with the following CSS, I'm unable to put them as:

> [LEFT SIDEBAR][CONTENT][RIGHT SIDEBAR]

```
#content{
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 48.0%;
}

#left-sidebar,
#right-sidebar{
  position: relative;
  width: 23.4%;
}

#left-sidebar{
  float: left;
}

#right-sidebar{
  float: right;
}
```

It takes the order to the visual website to:

> [CONTENT][LEFT SIDEBAR][RIGHT SIDEBAR]

**How can I stack the three items into such an order and put the respective CSS so that I can achieve a web look like (1), but a look in mobile devices like (2)?**

```
(1)
+-------++----------------++-------+
|       ||                ||       |
|       ||                ||       |
| LEFT  ||     CONTENT    || RIGHT |
|       ||                ||       |
|       ||                ||       |
+-------++----------------++-------+

(2)
+------+
| CONT |
|      |
+------+
| LFT  |
+------+
| RHT  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the widths, you can simply change the positioning on a resize from `absolute` to `relative`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LBHE2/)

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='content'>Content</div>
    <div id='left'>Left</div>
    <div id='right'>Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#left, #right, #content {
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
}
#left {
    background:yellow;
    width:23.4%;
}
#content {
    background:red;
    width:48.0%;
    left:23.4%;
}
#right {
    background:blue;
    left:71.4%;
    width:23.4%;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    #left, #right, #content {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        left:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never tried an `absolute` positioning for stacked `div`s. Is that browser and content safe?

Comment: If you mean compatible, yes

Comment: I did it like: `<div id="inner-container" style="position: relative;"> ... <div class="clearfix"></div> </div>`, I can't set a fixed height for the holders. And that's why the `<footer>` is overlapping the body content, as the `#inner-container` (i.e. `#wrapper`) is not taking it's `clear` float at the end because of the use of `absolute` positioning inside.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - Its hard to know what you mean as you are referring to code you havent posted elsewhere.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - you need to apply the code in my answer to your code and it will work- have you tried?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam - you can also accomplish this without using position:absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/LBHE2/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54185/discussion-between-mayeenul-islam-and-sw4).